# Erlang mqtt keeps crashing

Tags: erlang, mqtt, emq

My emqttd server crashes often and I can't figure out why. Here's a snippet of the error.log file:

```
2018-04-19 10:53:05.215 [error] <0.6456.0> gen_server <0.6456.0> terminated with reason: no match of right hand value {pubrel,76,{1524,127985,200713}} in emqttd_session:acked/3 line 736
2018-04-19 10:53:05.216 [error] <0.6456.0> CRASH REPORT Process <0.6456.0> with 1 neighbours exited with reason: no match of right hand value {pubrel,76,{1524,127985,200713}} in emqttd_session:acked/3 line 736 in gen_server2:terminate/3 line 1157
2018-04-19 10:53:05.216 [error] <0.1107.0> Supervisor emqttd_session_sup had child session started with {emqttd_session,start_link,undefined} at <0.6456.0> exit with reason no match of right hand value {pubrel,76,{1524,127985,200713}} in emqttd_session:acked/3 line 736 in context child_terminated
2018-04-19 10:53:05.216 [error] <0.1150.0> Supervisor 'esockd_connection_sup - <0.1150.0>' had child connection started with emqttd_client:start_link([{client_idle_timeout,30000},{client_enable_stats,false},{max_clientid_len,1024},{max_packet_size,...}]) at <0.6458.0> exit with reason no match of right hand value {pubrel,76,{1524,127985,200713}} in emqttd_session:acked/3 line 736 in context connection_crashed
```

The network on the machine seems fine.

Here's some lines from erlang.log that seem relevant:

```
07:33:17.024 [critical] Mnesia overload: {dump_log,write_threshold}
07:33:17.024 [error] Unexpected Info: {mnesia_system_event,{mnesia_overload,{dump_log,write_threshold}}}
07:34:49.954 [error] gen_server <0.32644.1437> terminated with reason: no match of right hand value {pubrel,16,{1524,116089,953795}} in emqttd_session:acked/3 line 736
07:34:49.955 [error] CRASH REPORT Process <0.32644.1437> with 1 neighbours exited with reason: no match of right hand value {pubrel,16,{1524,116089,953795}} in emqttd_session:acked/3 line 736 in gen_server2:terminate/3 line 1157
```

Can anyone tell me what these error messages mean? If I need to post additional log data or configuration details I can.

EDIT: free -mh output and htop output

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:           7.8G        203M        5.9G         80M        1.7G        7.2G
Swap:          509M         36M        473M
```

[image: htop output]

Comment: What is the machine config you are using?

Comment: @TarunLalwani what do you mean exactly? How much memory etc. the machine has?

Comment: Yes, RAM and CPU to be precise

Comment: it's got 8GB RAM and 4 cores. Can't really see the speed of the cores right now. Do you think it's just overloading?

Comment: I don't think so, but you should add the output of `htop` (screenshot) and `free -mh` to just indicate what the system state looks like

Comment: Do you wait answer to pubrel call in a loop? Or is that part your code, where it throws now?

Comment: See this there is same issue https://github.com/erlio/vernemq/issues/41

Comment: You are probably running into some limits.